# SmtpResponse exception in constructor

Tags: exchange-server

I'm updating our spamfilter from Exchange 2013 to 2019. My transport agent references these two DLLs:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Common.dll
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.dll
```

Both of the following lines of code generate an exception, when I replace the 2013 versions of these DLLs with the new ones from Exchange 2019:

```
// Exchange 2019 syntax
SmtpResponse smtpResponse = SmtpResponse.Create("550", "5.7.1", "A single string");


// Exchange 2013 syntax (deprecated under 2019, but still compiles)
SmtpResponse smtpResponse = new SmtpResponse("550", "5.7.1", "A single string");
```

The exception message is:

> Der Typeninitialisierer für
>   "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.Smtp.SmtpResponse" hat eine
>   Ausnahme verursacht."* The type initializer for … has generated an
>   exception.

Even this simple line leads to an Exception:

```
SmtpResponse smtpResponse = new SmtpResponse();
```

Any ideas why the constructor of SmtpResponse throws this exception? On Exchange 2013, this code has been running flawlessly for years.

Answer (score 0):

OK, on Exchange Server 2019, `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.dll` has a new dependency, `Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics.dll`. This DLL is NOT in the Public folder of your Exchange Server as the other DLLs, but in the bin folder.

Copying Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics.dll to my local bin folder solved the problem.